# Is there any one who knows to solve OSSpinLockLock issue when I programming a game using SpriteKit iOS7?

Tags: ios7, spinlock, xcode5.0.1

OSSpinLockLock was caused repeatedly and lldb reveals no appropriate callStackSymbols for this.

The following is what I got from lldb of Xcode Version 5.0.1 (5A2034a)

I tried to get more symbols by [NSThread callStackSymbols] but  it is not effective in this case.

This happens only with SpriteKit (iOS7).   I've checked tens of times around SKEmitterNodes but it has no bug inside.
Birzarrely enough, sometimes copyWithZone: message can't operate normally in high speed projectiles as the followings:

SKEmitterNode * template=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cannonball_flame" ofType:@"sks"]];
....
...
[template copy]; // --> not good in some cases

Is there anyon who knows to solve this problem?   Is it caused by SpriteKit bug?

02NOV2013 1:31AM
call stack 0

```
libsystem_platform.dylib`OSSpinLockLock:
0x38ef1654:  movs   r1, #1

libsystem_platform.dylib`spin_lock + 2:
0x38ef1656:  ldrex  r2, [r0]
0x38ef165a:  cmp    r2, #0
0x38ef165c:  it     ne
0x38ef165e:  bne.w  0x38ef4a94                ; _OSSpinLockLockSlow$shim
0x38ef1662:  strex  r2, r1, [r0]
0x38ef1666:  cmp    r2, #0
0x38ef1668:  bne    0x38ef1656                ; spin_lock + 2
0x38ef166a:  dmb    ish
0x38ef166e:  bx     lr

call stack 1
SpriteKit`SKSpinLockSync(int*, void () block_pointer):
0x30c2d924:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
0x30c2d926:  add    r7, sp, #12
0x30c2d928:  push.w {r8, r10, r11}
0x30c2d92c:  sub.w  r4, sp, #64
0x30c2d930:  bic    r4, r4, #15
0x30c2d934:  mov    sp, r4
0x30c2d936:  vst1.64 {d8, d9, d10, d11}, [r4, :128]!
0x30c2d93a:  vst1.64 {d12, d13, d14, d15}, [r4, :128]
0x30c2d93e:  sub    sp, #64
0x30c2d940:  mov    r4, r0
0x30c2d942:  mov    r0, r1
0x30c2d944:  str    r4, [sp, #4]
0x30c2d946:  blx    0x30c44114                ; symbol stub for: dispatch_async$shim
0x30c2d94a:  movw   r2, #1712
0x30c2d94e:  ldr    r1, [pc, #140]            ; SKSpinLockSync(int*, void () block_pointer) + 184
0x30c2d950:  movt   r2, #2171
0x30c2d954:  str    r0, [sp, #8]
0x30c2d956:  add    r0, sp, #12
0x30c2d958:  add    r2, pc
0x30c2d95a:  ldr    r2, [r2]
0x30c2d95c:  add    r1, pc
0x30c2d95e:  str    r2, [sp, #36]
0x30c2d960:  str    r1, [sp, #40]
0x30c2d962:  ldr    r1, [pc, #124]            ; SKSpinLockSync(int*, void () block_pointer) + 188
0x30c2d964:  str    r7, [sp, #44]
0x30c2d966:  str.w  sp, [sp, #52]
0x30c2d96a:  orr    r1, r1, #1
0x30c2d96e:  add    r1, pc
0x30c2d970:  str    r1, [sp, #48]
0x30c2d972:  movs   r1, #1
0x30c2d974:  str    r1, [sp, #16]
0x30c2d976:  blx    0x30c44274                ; symbol stub for: SKCRenderPassNew::operator=(SKCRenderPassNew const&)
0x30c2d97a:  mov    r0, r4
0x30c2d97c:  blx    0x30c44234                ; symbol stub for: +[SKOpenGLNode openGLNodeWithViewportSize:]
0x30c2d980:  ldr    r0, [sp, #8]
0x30c2d982:  movs   r2, #2
0x30c2d984:  ldr    r1, [r0, #12]
0x30c2d986:  ldr    r0, [sp, #8]
0x30c2d988:  str    r2, [sp, #16]
0x30c2d98a:  blx    r1
0x30c2d98c:  movs   r0, #3
0x30c2d98e:  str    r0, [sp, #16]
0x30c2d990:  ldr    r0, [sp, #4]
0x30c2d992:  blx    0x30c44244                ; symbol stub for: -[SKOpenGLNode needsRenderForTime:]
0x30c2d996:  ldr    r0, [sp, #8]
0x30c2d998:  blx    0x30c44104                ; symbol stub for: objc_copyWeak$shim
0x30c2d99c:  add    r0, sp, #12
0x30c2d99e:  blx    0x30c44294                ; symbol stub for: SKCRenderPassNew::~SKCRenderPassNew()
0x30c2d9a2:  add    r4, sp, #64
0x30c2d9a4:  vld1.64 {d8, d9, d10, d11}, [r4, :128]!
0x30c2d9a8:  vld1.64 {d12, d13, d14, d15}, [r4, :128]
0x30c2d9ac:  sub.w  r4, r7, #24
0x30c2d9b0:  mov    sp, r4
0x30c2d9b2:  pop.w  {r8, r10, r11}
0x30c2d9b6:  pop    {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
0x30c2d9b8:  ldr    r0, [sp, #16]
0x30c2d9ba:  cmp    r0, #3
0x30c2d9bc:  bls    0x30c2d9c0                ; SKSpinLockSync(int*, void () block_pointer) + 156
0x30c2d9be:  trap   
0x30c2d9c0:  tbb    [pc, r0]
0x30c2d9c4:  lsls   r2, r0, #8
0x30c2d9c6:  movs   r2, r0
0x30c2d9c8:  ldr    r4, [sp, #20]
0x30c2d9ca:  ldr    r0, [sp, #8]
0x30c2d9cc:  blx    0x30c44104                ; symbol stub for: objc_copyWeak$shim
0x30c2d9d0:  mov.w  r0, #4294967295
0x30c2d9d4:  str    r0, [sp, #16]
0x30c2d9d6:  mov    r0, r4
0x30c2d9d8:  blx    0x30c44284                ; symbol stub for: SKCRenderPassNew::~SKCRenderPassNew()
0x30c2d9dc:  ldr    r3, [sp, #400]
0x30c2d9de:  movs   r1, r0
0x30c2d9e0:  lsls   r6, r0, #1
0x30c2d9e2:  movs   r0, r0


didBeginContact: Hit Tree
(lldb) po [NSThread callStackSymbols]
<_NSCallStackArray 0x7f9fe40>(
0   ???                                 0x00571654 0x0 + 5707348,
1   NaughtyBirds                        0x000e7175 main + 0,
2   SpriteKit                           0x30bf38fd <redacted> + 300,
3   SpriteKit                           0x30bf67ef <redacted> + 42,
4   SpriteKit                           0x30c163a5 <redacted> + 3136,
5   SpriteKit                           0x30c262ab <redacted> + 354,
6   SpriteKit                           0x30c262ab <redacted> + 354,
7   SpriteKit                           0x30c262ab <redacted> + 354,
8   SpriteKit                           0x30beeb93 <redacted> + 174,
9   SpriteKit                           0x30c03449 <redacted> + 324,
10  SpriteKit                           0x30c00add <redacted> + 820,
11  SpriteKit                           0x30bfe51b <redacted> + 130,
12  SpriteKit                           0x30c20c87 <redacted> + 254,
13  libglInterpose.dylib                0x002bb5ff -[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 270,
14  QuartzCore                          0x309dfad3 <redacted> + 98,
15  QuartzCore                          0x309df87d <redacted> + 344,
16  IOMobileFramebuffer                 0x3360f76d <redacted> + 104,
17  IOKit                               0x2f266be5 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 248,
18  CoreFoundation                      0x2e544b81 <redacted> + 136,
19  CoreFoundation                      0x2e54f777 <redacted> + 34,
20  CoreFoundation                      0x2e54f713 <redacted> + 346,
21  CoreFoundation                      0x2e54dedf <redacted> + 1406,
22  CoreFoundation                      0x2e4b8471 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524,
23  CoreFoundation                      0x2e4b8253 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106,
24  GraphicsServices                    0x331f22eb GSEventRunModal + 138,
25  UIKit                               0x30d6d845 UIApplicationMain + 1136,
26  NaughtyBirds                        0x000e7259 main + 228,
27  libdyld.dylib                       0x38ddaab7 <redacted> + 2
```

)

(lldb) bt all
* thread #1: tid = 0xcf5af, 0x38ef1656 libsystem_platform.dylib`spin_lock + 2, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x38ef1656 libsystem_platform.dylib`spin_lock + 2
    frame #1: 0x30c2d980 SpriteKit`SKSpinLockSync(int*, void () block_pointer) + 92
    frame #2: 0x30bf38fc SpriteKit`-[SKTexture loadImageData] + 300
    frame #3: 0x30bf67ee SpriteKit`-[SKTexture size] + 42
    frame #4: 0x30c163a4 SpriteKit`SKCEmitterSprite::update(double) + 3136
    frame #5: 0x30c262aa SpriteKit`SKCSprite::update(double) + 354
    frame #6: 0x30c262aa SpriteKit`SKCSprite::update(double) + 354
    frame #7: 0x30c262aa SpriteKit`SKCSprite::update(double) + 354
    frame #8: 0x30beeb92 SpriteKit`-[SKScene _update:] + 174
    frame #9: 0x30c03448 SpriteKit`-[SKView(Private) _update:] + 324
    frame #10: 0x30c00adc SpriteKit`-[SKView renderCallback:] + 820
    frame #11: 0x30bfe51a SpriteKit`__29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 130
    frame #12: 0x30c20c86 SpriteKit`-[SKDisplayLink *callbackForNextFrame:] + 254
    frame #13: 0x002bb5fe libglInterpose.dylib`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 270
    frame #14: 0x309dfad2 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 98
    frame #15: 0x309df87c QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 344
    frame #16: 0x3360f76c IOMobileFramebuffer`IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 104
    frame #17: 0x2f266be4 IOKit`IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 248
    frame #18: 0x2e544b80 CoreFoundation`*_CFMachPortPerform + 136
    frame #19: 0x2e54f776 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
    frame #20: 0x2e54f712 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
    frame #21: 0x2e54dede CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1406
    frame #22: 0x2e4b8470 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
    frame #23: 0x2e4b8252 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #24: 0x331f22ea GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 138
    frame #25: 0x30d6d844 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
    frame #26: 0x000e7258 NaughtyBirds`main(argc=1, argv=0x27d2bc4c) + 228 at main.m:18

thread #5: tid = 0xcf5de, 0x38e91550 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__semwait_signal + 24, name = 'gputools.smt_poll.0x15d305b0
    frame #0: 0x38e91550 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__semwait_signal + 24
    frame #1: 0x38e024ec libsystem_c.dylib`nanosleep + 172
    frame #2: 0x38e0243c libsystem_c.dylib`usleep + 52
    frame #3: 0x00350ad0 GPUToolsCore`smt_poll_thread_entry(void*) + 124
    frame #4: 0x38ef7c5c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 140
    frame #5: 0x38ef7bce libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 102

thread #7: tid = 0xcf5e0, 0x38e7e838 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    frame #0: 0x38e7e838 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 24
    frame #1: 0x38dcd0d4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
    frame #2: 0x38dc7622 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 38

thread #8: tid = 0xcf655, 0x38e91c7c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
    frame #0: 0x38e91c7c libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 8
    frame #1: 0x38ef5e0a libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 310

thread #9: tid = 0xcf664, 0x38e7ea84 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 20
    frame #0: 0x38e7ea84 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 20
    frame #1: 0x38e7e880 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 40
    frame #2: 0x2df353c2 AudioToolbox`AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 106
    frame #3: 0x2df38600 AudioToolbox`AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 8
    frame #4: 0x2de75772 AudioToolbox`CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 210
    frame #5: 0x38ef7c5c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 140
    frame #6: 0x38ef7bce libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 102
(lldb)

Comment: Duplicate question. check out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449163/what-is-skspinlocksync-in-sprite-kit-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score -4):

Finally I found a solution.   All postings to be able to be obtained from internet search was void to the solution.   Sometimes, a special action type would cause this problem, not by corrupt or missing texture in the bundle if the action contains a concept of multithreading.  And I did solve it!

Comment: I have been having this problem for a long time and I would love to understand your answer better.  Can you explain a little more?